# Resharper Alt Enter not working

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Help, I can't function without `Resharper`. All of a sudden my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> shortcut (to bring up the action list) has stopped working. Anybody experienced this or know how to fix?

Comment: why not select Chuck Conway's answer as the correct one? It fixes this specific problem without killing all your other shortcut customisations.

Comment: +1 for the "cant function without `Resharper`" I came here with the exact same worries! my go to phrase was "cant function without `Resharper`"

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Symptom A: the menu pops up for a split second, then goes away.  Fix using the following steps in numerical order.

Symptom B: pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> does nothing.  Fix using **Step #2 first** then try Step #1 if the issue persists.

1. Perform a Visual Studio reset:

   - Run `cmd.exe` as Administrator
   - `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\`
   - `devenv.exe /ResetSettings`
2. Re-apply Visual Studio keyboard scheme:

   - *(VS2013 latest ReSharper)* `ReSharper > Options > Environment > Keyboard & Menus > ReSharper Platform keyboard scheme: Visual Studio > Apply Scheme > Save`. This will reset the shortcut keys for `ReSharper`.
   - *(older versions)* `ReSharper > Options > Environment > General > Visual Studio Integration > Apply`

Comment: Reinstalled ReSharper after doing this and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Instead of reinstalling ReSharper after the VS reset, you might be able to fix it by going into the ReSharper options and do "Environment -> General -> Visual Studio Integration -> Apply". This will reset the shortcut keys for ReSharper.

Comment: +1 for Josh's comment - I found that just clicking "Apply" worked without having to reset VS.

Comment: Thanks! Worked with Josh's comment. You should warn that you'll lose your VS settings after doing this.

Comment: I reset my keyboard profile (in vs options) and re-applied the resharper vs keyboard scheme. Nothing worked. I've found it's specific to a particular solution. A big huge nasty 31 assembly solution. I also deleted the solutions _Resharper folder - the little pencil just never appears on the active line. :(

Comment: I reset a bunch of things but nothing worked then I opened Resharper | Manage Options. There are separate resharper settings – 3 levels in my case, my pc’s, my personal settings for the solution and the teams settings for the solution. Resetting these restored my context menu, give that a whirl if u run into that problem.

Comment: Didn't work for me: this did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514642/resharper-8-quickfix-shortcut-altenter-gone

Comment: My resharper wasn't working at all --stopped accepting keyboard input. This solution fixed it all!!

Comment: Downvoted because this resets keyboard shortcuts. The other solution fixes this issue only without causing any more

Comment: At the time of writing, that was the only known solution. This is how stack overflow works. If better solutions arise, they will get up voted and moved to the top. Down voting is for things that are wrong, which is why you actually get points taken away from you when you down vote

Comment: In VS2015 / R#10 you will find the option that Josh wrote about 8 years ago in the ReSharper Options > General > Keyboard & Menus. Then click the "Apply Scheme" button.

Comment: I closed all other instances of VS that I had running.  Removed an extra mapping to ALT+Enter and restarted VS.  No reinstall of Resharper necessary.

Comment: helped me with VS2017 and ReSharper 2017.1.3 Alt + Return Bug

Comment: I was able to do #2, then restart vs.net and it resolved my issue

Answer (score 134):

You can try going `ReSharper` -> `Options > IntelliSense > General` and switching the radio buttons and clicking `OK`. Then switching back to the previously selected radiobutton.

**Edit**

Here is how to change/assign keyshort cuts in `Visual Studio/Resharper` from [JetBrains Knowledge Base](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Options/shortcuts.html)

The command you are looking for is called "ReSharper_QuickFix". In version 8, this is called "Resharper_AltEnter".

Comment: Bump for the `Resharper_AltEnter` shortcut, mine was mapped improperly and it resolved the issue for me

Comment: Resharper_AltEnter was the solution

Answer (score 115):

I had to do this:

1. Resharper -> Options -> Keyboard & Menus
2. Select "ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA"
3. Click "Apply Scheme"
4. Click "Save"
5. Resharper -> Options -> Keyboard & Menus
6. Select "Visual Studio"
7. Click "Apply Scheme"
8. Click "Save"

Comment: Thanks. This helped me and non of other methods didn't in my case.

Comment: I did "None", then "Visual Studio", and it worked for me. (VS2012 + ReSharper 8.2)

Comment: Works on my machine!

Comment: And I can confirm that this works for VisualStudio 2017 as well

Comment: I have a new rig at home, win10, VS 2017 and had the same problem I had all those years ago.  Proud to report this fix still works! (had to look it up here though :) )

Answer (score 58):

To get your <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> combination working you should set "ReSharper_AltEnter" action (formerly "ReSharper_QuickFix(Text Editor)") for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> in `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard`.[image: Keyboard Options] Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> in "Press shortcuts here:" field and expand "Shortcuts currently used by:" drop list. It is not necessary for action to be selected, it just should be there. If it is not - go to `Resharper->Options->Environment->Keyboard & Menus` and apply "ReSharper 2.x or Intellij IDEA" scheme.

After that, ReSharper acions will work for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> even when you'll apply "Visual Studio" or "None" keyboard scheme. To be exact, for "Visual Studio" schema selecting window will be shown and for "None" ReSharper action will be executed by default. Hereby, "ReSharper_AltEnter" for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> is the key moment to get your ReSharper actions working!

Comment: For new versions of R# the command named "ReSharper_AltEnter"

Comment: That should be an answer (together with comment from Michael).
Resetsettings will reset all the user-defined settings - be aware!

Comment: From "Show commands containing", search "ReSharper_AltEnter", then add "Alt+Enter"in "Press shortcut keys", then "Assign" to renew.

Comment: I cant find the quick fix commant in show commands containing dialog. I have a newer version of resharper I guess

Answer (score 22):

Thanks Josh ... your suggestion worked for me. The steps I took on `VS 2010` were:

> ReSharper -> Options -> Environment -> Visual Studio Integration ->
>   Keyboard Shortcuts (Visual Studio) -> Apply Scheme (button)

Comment: Works for me, a note though: i've done this before and it does take a while. I got impatient and ctrl+alt+del'd the process, after that I couldn't get it to work again. The morale of the story kids: be patient :)

Comment: Apply scheme worked for me. unfortunately, this was the last option I tried.

Comment: I'm on ReSharper 7, and it appears that the menu items have been renamed. For the benefit of others, I found this button under ReSharper -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard & Menus -> Keyboard Shortcuts (Visual Studio) -> Apply Scheme (button)

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the answers above, there is an easy way Using **Resharper 3.3**

in Visual Studio 2017

- Open  **Tools** > **Options** or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- Under **Environment** tab > **Keyboard**
- Search for "**AltEnter**" and select `Resharper_AltEnter`
- Add a new shortcut  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- **Assign** > **OK**

and it worked...

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I had to do this:

1. Go to **Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard**
2. Press **Reset**
3. Go to **ReSharper -> Options... -> Environment -> Keyboard & Menus**
4. Select the **ReSharper keyboard scheme**
5. Finally, select **Visual Studio**, click on **Apply Scheme** and then **Save**

.. and it worked!

Answer (score 6):

I have encounter the same problem. you might be able to fix it by going into the

> ReSharper > Options > Environment > Keyboard & Menus > check ReSharper
>   2.x or IntelliJ IDEA -> Apply

This will reset the shortcut keys for `ReSharper`.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found that Kwex solution works but sometimes it doesn't put all of the shortcuts back.

I found this strange solution

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-287309

> i found an ad-hoc solution which seems to do the trick for now (not
>   sure if this is universal, but it worked here. Twice):
>
> 1. I exported my current settings which had the not working ReSharper shortcuts set (Tools-Import/Export->Export selected...)
> 2. I imported the settings again (Tools->Import/Export->Import selected...)
>
> Kind of a hack perhaps, but the keyboard shortcuts seem to work.
>
> solution helped fix the rest (especially Control + B - go to
>   definition)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing to be done is to set the keyboard shortcut under `Options > Environment > Keyboard`. You add `ReSharper_QuickFix` to your search and enter the shortcut keys under `Press shortcut keys:` textbox and click `Assign` and `OK`. Done, You don't have to reset anything.

Answer (score 1):

As an additional reason for why <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> would not work if analysis is turned `off` **on the file**. If you look in the upper right of the of the code editing window just to the right of the scroll bar and there is a `pause` icon instead of the `warning`, or `OK` symbols `R#` will not give you any menu on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>.

If this is disabled you can enable it from the `R#` options menu under `Code Inspection >  Settings` and make sure that `Enable code analysis` is checked.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after upgrading ReSharper to version 8.0.14.856 from some v8 EAP.  I use the IntelliJ shortcuts.  My <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> stopped working.  To get it back I used the

```
ReSharper | Options | KeyBoard & Menus.
```

I picked the Visual Studio radio button, then Apply Scheme button, then selected the Resharper 2x or IntelliJ IDEA radio button, then another Apply Scheme.  My <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> started working again.

I write this because the issue came in the newest version of the tool, and the comments by Bart and Josh, while still substantively still correct, refer to menu items that moved a little since they wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by installing "IntelliJ keyboard shortcut extension". Didn't find any of the Reshaper options.

Comment: The only solution in 2021 .. thanks bro !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same when I upgraded Vista -> Win 7. I my case, I had set my keyboard to 'United States-international'. Pressing the  +  will actually give you  +  + . Solution: set keyboard to 'US'.

Answer (score 0):

if any of the other solution does not works try Deleting the `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\ReSharper` folder. This will restores ReSharper to working condition in VS2012 as well as VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Right-Alt "compose" key was preventing windows from seeing that it was being pressed, so it just saw "enter". Removing the compose key fixed it for me..

Answer (score 0):

**One other solution to this:**

This can be caused by ReSharper extensions that are no longer compatible with the installed version of ReSharper. Uninstalling the extensions typically fixes it for me.

I have typically seen this when using the EAP versions of R#. For example, as of this writing, the current EAP R# 2021.3 has several plugins that are incompatible and cause exceptions on load that cause light bulb actions / alt+enter to fail to load: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-486452

Note: You may see error messages pop up when Visual Studio starts up that will be caused by said incompatible exceptions.