# What is the name of the ReSharper's Quick Fix command

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I want to reassign the Alt-Enter keystroke (for the light bulb suggestions) to another key but I can't find it in the Options->Keyboard list. All the ReSharper commands seem to have `ReSharper_` in the name. but I can't figure out what name they used for the quick fixes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Resharper 8 seems to have renamed this to Resharper_AltEnter.

Answer (score 2):

I found it under the `ReSharper_QuickFix`, as you'd expected. (VS 2012)

See alse https://stackoverflow.com/a/1596353/1679310

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned I'm trying out R#8 EAP, there must be something broken with the keyboard shortcuts because ReSharper_QuickFix is not there. At least I can stop looking.