# Resharper 8 - Quickfix shortcut Alt+Enter gone

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, resharper

In Visual Studio 2012/2013, I want to reassign the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> key combination to the "Quickfix" (triggering the menu from the light bulb) because it is not working anymore. I can't. I have tried the following (I am aware that some of the suggestions refer to VS 2010 and older R# versions):

- Tried to change manually in `Tools` - `Options` - `Keyboard`: the former ReSharper_QuickFix entry is gone, see [ReSharper_QuickFix gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjVqa.png)
- Tried Resharper_AltEnter as suggested in [What is the name of the ReSharper's Quick Fix command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227312/what-is-the-name-of-the-resharpers-quick-fix-command) - nothing, no shortcut
- Switched back and forth settings in `ReSharper` -> `Options` -> `Keyboard & Menus` as described in [Resharper Alt Enter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596328/resharper-alt-enter-not-working) - nothing
- Switched back and forth settings in `ReSharper` -> `Options` -> `IntelliSense` -> `General` as also described in [Resharper Alt Enter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596328/resharper-alt-enter-not-working) to no avail
- Tried other suggestions from the same page
- Sledgehammer approach: run devenv.exe /ResetSettings - nope
- Search SO and the web up and down - found nothing

I have not yet had the nerve to re-install R# or even VS.

**How can I get a standard set of R# keyboard shortcuts into Visual Studio?** I'd gladly wipe out everything that is there just to get back my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> Quickfix..

Comment: The R# `Options | Keyboard & Menus` page has a Note at the bottom, have you tried what it says there?

Comment: @AakashM: Yes I did. Didn't help.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem right now...

Comment: @Offler: No, unfortunately not. I'd post it here if I found one - please do the same.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Please try this:

- remove all mapping for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> shortcut here Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard (to find out mapped actions, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> in "Press shortcut keys" field and look at the list in "Shortcut currently used by" dropdown);

After removing:

- Type ReSharper_AltEnter in "Show command containing" field;
- Select "Text Editor" in "Use new shortcut in" dropdown;
- Press Alt+Enter in "Press shortcut keys" field | Assign;
- Select "XAML UI Designer" in "Use new shortcut in" dropdown;
- Press Alt+Enter in "Press shortcut keys" field | Assign;

Comment: Totally works.  Why ReSharper renamed Reshraper_QuickFix (what it is) to Resharper_AltEnter (the default shortcut) is completely beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 7):

They changed the name of this shortcut to Resharper_AltEnter.

Comment: As stated in the question, I have found and tried this, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I'd upgraded to VS Professional 2013 (update 3) about a week ago.  I then installed Resharper and was re-tooling a few projects with Resharper for a few days.  All was going well, then things went haywire.  I tried all the suggestions in this post and elsewhere.  This included un-installing and re-installing resharper.  Un-installing and re-installing VS. Nothing seemed to be fixing it

Until at some point I tried what turned out to be the fix:   uninstalling a couple of the R# extensions:  Resharper.ExternalAnnotations, Nuget Support for Resharper and Resharper Razor Plugin.

Not sure which was causing the issue.  But things seem to be working normally now.

I also went further and installed the latest ReSharper 8.2.3 - https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/

Things are still ok [crossing fingers].

I have NOT installed any R# extensions.  I will try to figure out which was the offending extension after I have had a few days of rest for this issue.  So, in retrospect, it seems this problem started after I installed some offending R# extension.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Quick-Fixes.html

Merge Visual Studio Light Bulb actions into ReSharper bulb - set checkbox in R# settings