# ReSharper 9 - Shortcut Alt+Enter not work in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper-9.0

I had tried hard to make it work using suggestions from -

1) [Resharper Alt Enter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596328/resharper-alt-enter-not-working)

2) [Resharper 8 - Quickfix shortcut Alt+Enter gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514642/resharper-8-quickfix-shortcut-altenter-gone?lq=1)

But so far all failed.

Did anyone else faced same? Do you have any suggestions that can make it possible in VS 2015.

Comment: I wish I could have make it possible somehow. Each time I try to fix and waste a hour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the above solutions worked for me.
I solved the problem by updating the version of ReSharper to version 9.2

Comment: I had to upgrade to 9.2 from 9.0 then follow Erik's instructions.  Thanks, Fabio.

Comment: Upgrading is the only solution. Issue fixed.

Comment: Upgrade to 2016.3.2 and then ReSharper > Options > Keyboard & Menus > Apply Scheme

Answer (score 18):

I got it working again by going into VS 2015 Options-> Keyboard, then hitting Reset.  Then go back to resharper keyboard options and selecting the ReSharper scheme and hitting apply.

Comment: For some reason, the system was formatted. And after installing VS 2015 afresh, and trying suggestion, it didn't worked.

Comment: Thanks , this worked for me.  Running 9.2 when I had this issue.  Followed your steps, and my shortcuts are back.