# ReSharper Alt-Enter not working in some projects but works in others

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I've found that if I try to use the context menu that shows up after Alt-Enter in one of my projects in a soluition, and then select an action, it will simply do nothing.

This only seems to happen in projects which I've added to my solution as a "Add existing project". It does work in the projects that belong to that specific solution.

Comment: Check this question, i think can help you.

[Resharper alt enter not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596328/resharper-alt-enter-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it turns out that the problem was being caused by the Git tools for VS. Disabling them in `Tools -> Options -> Source control -> None` fixes the issue.

Resources:

- http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/24790716--Refactoring-failed-Files-still-read-only-error-message-when-applying-Quick-Fix
- http://www.core-techs.net/Blog/161/resharper-refactoring-failed-caused-by-visual-studio-2012-tfs-git-provider

Answer (score 2):

The following instruction helped me: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546989-ReSharper-stopped-working-for-a-single-specific-solution

1. Resharper -> Options -> General -> Clear Cache
2. Remove .sue file from solution folder (it is hidden somewhere under .vs folder)