# Why Alt + Insert do not work in visual basic c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, resharper

For create  auto property, need to press Alt + Insert . But it does not work.. Is there any problem in Re sharper?

Comment: Does the standard c# "Ctrl and ."  to create auto property work??

Comment: Not used this in a while, but might show the active shortcuts: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/83f59659-abc1-4bfa-9779-42f687af0481

Comment: No, it does not work . Have there other way to create auto property?

Comment: @RatanRoy: Does `Alt+Enter` somewhere else work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resharper Alt Enter not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596328/resharper-alt-enter-not-working)

Comment: @Matthias yes it's work now, after updating Resharper.